# How can I play Pixelmon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-pixelmon

I am playing Minecraft and would love to play the Pokemon version, Pixelmon. The only problem is, I don't know how to get Pixelmon.

Is it just something you download in Minecraft, or is it gotten separately? Do you know?

Comment: -1 for utter lack of research effort.

Comment: It looks like a mod you would install same as any other minecraft mods you would use.

Comment: @kotekzot IKR. Half the questions I answer are by people who were too lazy to use Google. The majority of the time I can just Google myself and summarize it in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

[PixelMon](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1276311-164-pixelmon-257-december-7th-2013/) is a mod for minecraft. Mods are add-on files that change how minecraft is played or how it looks or usually both to some extent. They can be difficult to install if your not computer savvy, and sometimes they are difficult to install even if you *are* computer savvy, but usually it's not too big of a problem if you pay attention and follow the instructions properly. The instructions to install a mod are almost always included in the forum thread dedicated to the mod. (linked above) The forum thread is also where the download link for the mod can usually be found.

**TL:DR**: You play Pixelmon by downloading and installing it. You will find the install file and instructions to install it in its forum thread on the Minecraft Forums.